# Setting a socket's local endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I need to create a socket which connects to a server process, but must be restricted to using a specified local adapter.  The default behaviour is to use whatever it can, but I need to make sure that a given socket only tries (for example), the LAN connection, if both wifi and LAN are available.

I am using C# and .NET 2.0.

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)` method is your friend. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind%28VS.80%29.aspx) at MSDN for the details.

To get all local adapters and their type look at [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: that should be System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().

Answer (score 7):

For the reference of others, I was having a problem using Bind because I was using the UdpClient class and accessing its internal Socket (via UdpClient.Client) which would throw a SocketException no matter how I tried to Bind. My [workaround](http://snipplr.com/view/28192/bind-a-socket-including-udpclient-and-tcpclient-to-a-local-network-interface-card-nic/) relies on creating and binding the Socket first, then assigning it to the UdpClient instance:

```
using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
{
    var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    socket.Bind(endPoint);
    using (var client = new UdpClient() {Client = socket})
    {
        var destinationIP = IPAddress.Broadcast;
        client.Connect(destinationIP, port);
        client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could You try to use bind() function?
Maybe this would do the trick.

On msdn I've found that:

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737550(VS.85).aspx)

> Remarks
>
> The bind function is required on an
>   unconnected socket before subsequent
>   calls to the listen function. It is
>   normally used to bind to either
>   connection-oriented (stream) or
>   connectionless (datagram) sockets. The
>   bind function may also be used to bind
>   to a raw socket (the socket was
>   created by calling the socket function
>   with the type parameter set to
>   SOCK_RAW). **The bind function may also
>   be used on an unconnected socket
>   before subsequent calls to the
>   connect**, ConnectEx, WSAConnect,
>   WSAConnectByList, or WSAConnectByName
>   functions before send operations.
>
> When a socket is created with a call
>   to the socket function, it exists in a
>   namespace (address family), but it has
>   no name assigned to it. **Use the bind
>   function to establish the local
>   association of the socket by assigning
>   a local name to an unnamed socket.**
>
> A name consists of three parts when
>   using the Internet address family: The
>   address family. A host address. A port
>   number that identifies the
>   application.

Comment: bind() is the right method to look, but the OP is asking for C#.