# Any way to access two wireless adaptors at the same time?

Tags: .net, wireless, adaptor

I need to access two devices which have wireless hosts (not through a router). That is, I attach to it like it were a wireless router. It has one IP address to hit, and I can't change it. And I have 2 of them. So I need to somehow 'hit' the 'same' IP address, but with one adapter attached to one device, and another wireless adapter attached to the other device. And each device has the same IP/Port. I hope that made sense.

I would REALLY like to do this with Unity, via Mono's .NET support, if possible, but will use a DLL if needed. That is, if it's possible.

So in summary, some way to designate each wireless adapter to attach to different devices, and hit the 'same' IP address/port, thus getting fed from two different sources, but into the same computer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about connecting and configuring wireless adapters.

Comment: It is about writing a function or procedure to access specific addresses through specific adapters, not how to configure hardware.

Comment: How do you plan to associate specific addresses to specific adapters, of not by connecting and configuring them?

Comment: Looks like what I want is a mashup of the TcpClient constructor and the Bind api described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508804/setting-a-sockets-local-endpoint