# Programmatically Use Specific Network Adapter

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, routes

On a particular computer, I have two network adapters. One is connected to an expensive IP provider, like satellite, while the other is connected to a less expensive provider, like an air card. The satellite connection is extremely reliable and always available, but much more expensive. The air card is sometimes in coverage, and when it is, it is less expensive.

In my application, there are some API calls that are critical and must happen when I need them to. Other API calls are less important.

Using C#, when I want to make a call to an important API (https endpoint), can I direct that call to use the network adapter bound to the satellite, and when I have a less critical call, can I force it to use the less expensive adapter if it is available? In other words, I would like to selectively use one gateway vs. another based on logic within my application.

If it is possible, what is the coding approach, and which class libraries would be involved.

Comment: You probably want to edit your question to ask more than a simple Yes/No question.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I will refine the question.

Comment: May be duplicate of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508804/setting-a-sockets-local-endpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a socket's local endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508804/setting-a-sockets-local-endpoint)